# Move semantics for a custom vector and allocators

Tags: c++, stdvector, move-semantics, allocator

I'm implementing a basic std::vector by using an allocator, following PPP by Stroustrup, and in particular I'm sure that all the functions like resize, push_back, emplace_back, and so on are okay.

What is really puzzling me a bit is the **copy and move semantics**: it works now, but I find it a bit too hard-coded and, more importantly, **it's leaking 1 byte in the move assignment**, as can be seen from this

```
==7853== LEAK SUMMARY:
==7853==    definitely lost: 1 bytes in 1 blocks
==7853==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7853==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

In the following the whole code. I'd like to see especially how the move assignment should be implemented, because I believe that a problem is the fact that I have to move an allocator, and I'm totally new to this topic.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <string>

template <typename T, typename Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
class Vector
{
private:
    Allocator allocator; //used to handle memory for the elements
    T *elem;
    std::size_t _size{};
    std::size_t _capacity{};

    void reserve(const std::size_t n)
    {
        if (_capacity < n) //if the capacity is smaller than what I want to allocate
        {
            T *tmp{std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::allocate(allocator, n)};
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < _size; ++i)
            {
                // allocator.construct(tmp + i, std::move(elem[i])); //tmp[i] = std::move(elem[i]);
                std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::construct(allocator, tmp + i, elem[i]);
            }

            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < _size; ++i)
            {
                std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::destroy(allocator, elem + i);
            }
            std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::deallocate(allocator, elem, _capacity);

            elem = tmp;    //move the pointer
            _capacity = n; //size increased!
        }
    }

    void check_and_increase_capacity()
    {
        if (_capacity == 0)
        {
            reserve(8);
        }
        else if (_size == _capacity)
        {
            reserve(2 * _size);
        }
    }

    template <typename O>
    void _push_back(O &&x)
    {
        check_and_increase_capacity();
        std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::construct(allocator, elem + _size, std::forward<O>(x));
        ++_size;
    }

public:
    explicit Vector(std::initializer_list<T> list) : elem{std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::allocate(allocator, list.size())}, _size{list.size()}, _capacity{list.size()}
    {
        std::uninitialized_copy(list.begin(), list.end(), begin());
        std::cout << "custom cstr"
                  << "\n";
    }

    ~Vector() noexcept
    {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < _size; ++i)
        {
            std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::destroy(allocator, elem + i); //call the destructor
        }
        std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::deallocate(allocator, elem, _capacity); //deallocate memory
    }

    T *begin() { return elem; }
    const T *begin() const { return elem; }

    T *end() { return elem + _capacity; }
    const T *end() const { return elem + _capacity; }

    Vector(const Vector &v) : allocator{std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::select_on_container_copy_construction(v.allocator)}, elem{std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::allocate(allocator, v._capacity)}
    {
        T *tmp{std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::allocate(allocator, _capacity)};
        _size = v._size;
        _capacity = v._capacity;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < _size; ++i)
        {
            std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::construct(allocator, tmp + i, std::move(v[i]));
        }

        std::uninitialized_copy(v.begin(), v.end(), begin()); //copy the elements

        //destroy and deallocate tmp
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < _size; ++i)
        {
            std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::destroy(allocator, tmp + i);
        }
        std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::deallocate(allocator, tmp, _capacity);
    }

    Vector &operator=(const Vector &v)
    {
        T *tmp{std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::allocate(allocator, v._capacity)};
        std::uninitialized_copy(v.begin(), v.end(), begin()); //copy the elements
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v._size; ++i)
        {
            std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::destroy(allocator, elem + i);
        }
        std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::deallocate(allocator, elem, _capacity);
        elem = tmp;
        _size = v._size;
        _capacity = v._capacity;
        return *this;
    }

    Vector(Vector &&v) noexcept : allocator{std::move(v.allocator)}
    {

        elem = v.elem;
        v.elem = nullptr;
        _size = v._size;
        v._size = 0;
        _capacity = v._capacity;
        v._capacity = 0;
        std::cout << elem << "\n";
    }

    Vector &operator=(Vector &&v) noexcept
    {
        std::cout << "move assignment"
                  << "\n";
        allocator = std::move(v.allocator);
        elem = v.elem;
        v.elem = nullptr;
        _size = v._size;
        v._size = 0;
        _capacity = v._capacity;
        v._capacity = 0;

        return *this;
    }

    void push_back(const T &x)
    {
        _push_back(x);
    }

    void push_back(T &&x)
    {
        _push_back(std::move(x));
    }

    template <typename... Types>
    void emplace_back(Types &&...args)
    {
        check_and_increase_capacity();
        std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::construct(allocator, elem + _size, std::forward<Types>(args)...);
    }

    T &operator[](const std::size_t i) noexcept { return elem[i]; }
    const T &operator[](const std::size_t i) const noexcept { return elem[i]; }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Vector &v)
    {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v._size; i++)
        {
            std::cout << v[i] << "\n";
        }
        return os;
    }

    void resize(const std::size_t newsize, T val = T{})
    {
        reserve(newsize);
        for (std::size_t i = _size; i < newsize; ++i)
        {
            std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::construct(allocator, elem + i, val);
        }

        //destroy all the new extra elements
        for (std::size_t i = newsize; i < _size; ++i)
        {
            std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::destroy(allocator, elem + i); //just destroy them, don't call release the memory!
        }

        _size = newsize;
    }
};

struct Foo
{
    std::string _s;
    Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "foo cstr"
                  << "\n";
    };
    explicit Foo(const std::string &s) : _s{s} {}
    ~Foo() = default;
};

int main()
{

    Vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    std::cout << v << "\n";
    v.push_back(11);
    std::cout << "After push_back \n"
              << v << "\n";

    Vector<Foo> w{{}, {}};
    w.emplace_back();

    v.resize(6);
    std::cout << "After resize \n"
              << v << "\n";

    // Copy/Move semantics tests
    Vector<int> v1{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    Vector<int> v2{v1};
    std::cout << "After copy cstr \n"
              << v2 << "\n";
    v2.push_back(20);
    std::cout << "after push_back \n"
              << v2 << "\n";

    Vector<int> v3{};
    v3 = v1;
    std::cout << v3 << "and v1: \n"
              << v1 << "\n";

    Vector<int> v4{std::move(v1)};
    std::cout << v4 << "and v1: \n"
              << v1 << "\n";

    Vector<int> v5{};
    v5 = std::move(v4);
    std::cout << v5 << "and v4: \n"
              << v4 << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems like you never free the storage previously pointed to by `elem` in `operator=`.

Comment: Yup. Move assignment operator should simply `swap` itself with the assigned-from object.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I did `elem = v.elem` and the set `elem = nullptr`, is this the source of problems?

Comment: Yes. Now try to paint a mental picture what would happen if `elem` was pointing to allocated memory that was allocated for `this` vector, previously, during the normal course of its operation.

Comment: @VoB You need to `Allocator::destroy` the previously owned elements, then `Allocator::deallocate` the previously owned storage.

Comment: I would simply `swap` the pointer, size, capacity, and the allocators between the two objects. The End.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Do you mean to use `std::swap`, or `std::move`?

Comment: I meant most certainly `std::swap`.

Comment: By the virtue of this being a move operation, the other object's lifetime is going to be pretty short. The "delay" will be minimal, even if there is going to be a delay at all. In most cases, the moved-from object will be destroyed immediately after the assignment. After all, it is (nearly always) a `prvalue`.

Comment: This is a vector. This is not a lock, with specific semantics.

Comment: Thanks guys for your discussion. @SamVarshavchik I tried to use swap by doing:        `
allocator{std::move(v.allocator)};`
`elem{std::swap(v.elem)};`
` _size{std::swap(v._size)};`
`_capacity{std::swap(v._capacity)};` but I got plenty of compiler errors. I think this is not what you mean, right?

Comment: Correct. This makes no sense. Perhaps you should look up the reference documentation for `std::swap`, and how to use it.

Comment: If you put a `std::unique_lock` in a vector it will be destroyed, when the moved-from vector gets destroyed, and release the underlying lock it held. Same thing that would happen, with the underlyting lock, if the `unique_lock` was moved into.

Comment: Not true. The moved from vector [will be in some valid but unspecified state](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Fair enough. I thought the guarantee on move construction also applied to move assignment. In that case, simply swapping should be fine.

Comment: `std::swap` takes two parameters, and not one. And that would be a somewhat odd way to use it, in a move assignment operator.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yeah that I know :-) The problem I was referring to is why my first move assignment is leaking. I can't figure it out

Comment: You already had a vector object. You already allocated something for its `elem`. Now you move-assigned another `vector` to it, and its `elem` get nuked from high orbit, by replacing it with some other object's `elem`, thus leaking all that memory.

Comment: okay, so in practice I did not deallocate the old space. But then why do `std::swap(elem,v.elem)` solves the problem? @SamVarshavchik

Comment: Because it moves `elem` to `v.elem`. `v` is another `vector` object, which will deallocate its `elem`, which was original `this` object's `elem`, when it gets destroyed, at some point later. An object that gets moved-from is still a perfectly kosher object "in some valid but unspecified state". When that object gets destroyed it gets destroyed just like any other object. Its destructor, if written correctly, deallocates its memory. Which used to belong to `this` object. The move assignment operator simply swaps all memory owned by both objects, each one ending up with what the other one had.

Comment: I think I got it now, let me have a last check: So, swapping the pointers (and all the other members) implies the following ( let me consider v4 and v5 as in the question). When the Vector `v4` goes out of scope, it will call the destructor for the memory owned by `v5`'s `elem`, because now the `elem` of `v4` is the one of the original vector `v5`. Conversely, when `v5` goes out of scope, its destructor will deallocate the memory owned by his `elem`, which was the original `elem` of `v4`. Is this correct? @SamVarshavchik

Comment: Correct. There is no other way to interpret "the move assignment operator simply swaps all memory owned by both objects, each one ending up with what the other one had", is there?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm sorry but now I'm a bit confused: doing your way, this move assignment does not "leave the source" empty", as written in PPP book: I mean, you just swapped everything: is this okay?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be ok? A move operation leaves the moved-from object in "some valid but unspecified state". An "empty" object certainly fits this requirement, but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I think it's not okay because I can't understand why, swapping the two Vectors, leaves the moved-from object in "some valid but unspecified state". For instance, what does it mean that $v_4$ is in some unspecified state?

Comment: It means that the state is not specified by the standard, but it must be a valid state. If, a result of a moved-from operation, the moved-from vector somehow ends up holding al ist of the first hundred prime numbers, then this would be a valid, but an unspecified, state.

Comment: Would you like to have a look at [this](https://github.com/CaglayanDokme/CPP-Exercises/blob/main/Containers/VectorContainer.h) custom implementation of Vector by me? It doesn't have the allocator policy, but it may be insightful for you :) Also, feel free to make suggestions in case of necessity